# How to make a get MS Graph Request with access code?

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to list items from some list in Office 365 SharePoint from a java native Windows app.

I'm using deprecated `office-365-java-sdk` to authenticate and get an access token. Yes, this SDK is deprecated but authentication still works. So, I have an access token.

So, next step is to make `GET` request. In Graph Explorer this URL works fine:

```
/v1.0/sites/root/lists/{site-id}/items
```

I followed documentation to build the request and I have to add a header with authentication token so this is my code:

```java
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/{0a506dcb-ecbc-40ed-bf2c-5912e78e3ca8}/items");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
{
    result.append(line);
}
rd.close();
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Authentication is working, because if access token header is not added, it returns a status error code of `401 Required authentication information is either missing or not valid for the resource`. But with an access code, it returns error code `400 Cannot process the request because it is malformed or incorrect`.

I'm stuck with this, I read the documentation again and again and after checking URL is right using Graph Explorer, I don't know if this is not the right way to include headers or what....

Comment: change the line `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/json");` to `conn.setRequestProperty("accept","application/json;odata=verbose");` and check

Comment: You're right! key of header should be "accept". however i had to delete "odata=verbose" because was returning bad request also. I put the request on Postman and "application/json;odata=ver‌​bose" is not supported. Please put the comment as respone and ill upvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct header to pass is `Accept: application/json`.

So, replace the `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/json");` with

`conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");`